# Which space is shown in html when there are adjacent spaces in adjacent elements?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, safari, opera

The following HTML file

```
<html><body>x <b> y</b></body><html>
```

looks like

```
<html><body>x <b>y</b></body><html>
```

and

```
<html><body>x<b> y</b></body><html>
```

The browser visualization of which of last two is equivalent to that of the original one?

Comment: I don't know why someone down-voted this question. It's clear and has a single correct answer, It even has consequences because the font-size of the body and b elements could be different, resulting in a different size gap between the x and  y depending on what space collapsing logic applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will show:

```
<html><body>x <b>y</b></body><html>
```

This has to do with word wrapping. You cannot use multiple spaces in a row in HTML without using a non-breaking space:

```
<html><body>x <b>&nbsp;y</b></body><html>
```

You can also change the white-space property to allow multiple spaces in CSS:

```
body {
  white-space:pre;
}
```

As shown in chrome inspector:
[image]

Comment: You didn't answer my question. I'm not interested in knowing how to show multiple spaces in a row.

Comment: @user1424739 I really hope this isn't a bad homework question. But, if it is you should try opening chrome inspector and hovering over the letter x and the letter y. It'll show you where the space is "visualized". Edited my answer...

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't. You can try it on your own what happens if you click only the space between `x` and `y`. chrome doesn't show where the space comes from.

Comment: @user1424739 Updated my answer again to clearly show you where it is coming from when using chrome inspector.

Comment: OK. I see what you mean. Your pointer is in the "Elements" tab in devtools. I just put the pointer in the browser window.

Comment: @user1424739 no problem! Chrome inspector can be weird. Hopefully the picture helped.

Comment: FWIW, the CSS spec precisely defines what should happen. The [CSS white-space processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/text.html#white-space-model) says that "4. If 'white-space' is set to 'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line',  [...] 2. any space (U+0020) following another space (U+0020) — even a space before the inline, if that space also has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap' or 'pre-line' — is removed." confirming what you inspected in Chrome